# How do I install pgcrypto in PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: postgresql, installation, postgresql-8.4, pgcrypto

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.10 and I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4 using `apt-get install postgresql`. I would like to use the built-in `sha1()` function, but it seems that I have to install `pgcrypto` first. But I don't know how to install it.

There is no `pgcrypto` if I try to install it using `apt-get install pgcrypto` and I don't find any files starting with `pgcrypto` in my system (I tried `find / -name "pgcrypto*"`).

How do I install pgcrypto so I can use the `digest('word-to-hash','sha1')` function in my database queries?

---

**Update:** I'm struggling to install pgcrypto on another Ubuntu machine. After installing the package using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4` how do I install it to my current PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Hi @Jonas, I'm not sure if you're having issues installing pgcrypto or if you're having issues getting it to work with your db install. It sounds like you have a repo issue. Verify this file exists on this path `/usr/local/pgsql/share/contrib/pgcrypto.sql` and let us know.

Comment: @jcolebrand: No I don't have a `/usr/local/pgsql` directory. The only place where I have `*.sql` files are in `/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/` but no crypto-related.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*For newer version of PG, check out the answer below by Dustin Kirkland*

It's an external module for Postgres. You should install the `postgresql-contrib-8.4` (or your pg version) package via apt:

```
apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4
```

Then you find the sql install file somewhere in the `/usr/share/postgresql` folder, and you'll need to run `pgcryto.sql` on the database.

```
psql -d <database> -f /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pgcrypto.sql
```

Or,

```
$ cd /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib
$ psql -d <database>
    psql (8.4.8)
    Type "help" for help.

    database=# \i pgcrypto.sql
```

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get install postgres-contrib` I get `E: Unable to locate package postgres-contrib`

Comment: I googled and now I have installed it using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-8.4` and then run `\i <path-to-pgcrypto>` using `psql`.

Comment: That's the way to do it. I slightly updated the answer to include the note on the version for the package

Comment: I try to install this on another ubuntu machine now, but it doesn't work. When I execute `\i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib` in `psql` I get this error: `could not read from input file: Is a directory`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, the command was `\i /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/pgcypto.sql`

Comment: Under postgresql 9.1 you type in command line:
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto

Answer (score 21):

## PostgreSQL 9.1+

Note that I'm working on Ubuntu 12.04, which uses postgresql 9.1.

There, I needed to:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

And then in my database:

```
postgres@ztrustee:~$ psql test
psql (9.1.3)
Type "help" for help.
test=# CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

And now I can use pgcrypto functionality, gen_random_bytes():

```
test=# create table test ( 
  id 
    text 
    not null 
    default encode( gen_random_bytes( 32 ), 'hex' ) 
    primary key, 
  value 
    text 
); 
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "test_pkey" for table "test"
CREATE TABLE
test=# \d test
                            Table "public.test"
 Column | Type |                         Modifiers                          
--------+------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id     | text | not null default encode(gen_random_bytes(32), 'hex'::text)
 value  | text | 
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

test=# insert into test (value) VALUES ('scoobydoo');
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from test;
                                id                                |   value   
------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 76dd5bd0120d3df797f932fbcb4f8aa5088e215ee2b920dddbff59c8595fbac7 | scoobydoo
```

Comment: I really like this answer, though you should have self-answered a question for 9.1+ (when this feature was added) As the OP clearly asked for 8.4 and his version doesn't support `CREATE EXTENSION ` (which makes the other answer strictly speaking correct.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version, there is no file path end with pgcrypto.sql .

Create an extension pgcrypto under the required user.

```
$ psql -U <username> -d mydb

psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

mydb=> CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;

CREATE EXTENSION
mydb=>
```

*If in case, the user does not have permission to create an extension, give superuser permission by login as postgres(default) user and try again.*

```
$ psql --u postgres

psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER USER <username> WITH SUPERUSER;

ALTER ROLE
```